# Export private key in pkcs8 format and public key in spki format in .net framework c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ecdsa, webcrypto-api

I am creating PublicKey and PrivateKey to sign and verify data in in .net core with below code.

```
ECDsa ecDsaVerify = ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP384);
byte[] publicKey = ecDsaVerify.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
byte[] privateKey = ecDsaVerify.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey();
```

And then I am sending private key to client side and then importing it using Webcrypto API of javascript like below.

```
var privateKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey("pkcs8", privateKeyBytes, { name: "ECDSA", namedCurve: "P-384" }, false, ["sign"] );
```

This works well in .net core.

But now same thing I am trying to implement in .net framework 4.7. So in that it don't have methods like `ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()` and `ExportPkcs8PrivateKey()`. It just have `ECDsa.ExportParameters()` method to export the keys.

So my question is how we can export the public and private key in **spki** and **pkcs8** in .net framework? OR how we can import keys generated from `ExportParameters()` into javascript?

Comment: For .NET Framework the support of PKCS#8 and X.509/SPKI format is sparse. Most convenient is creation and export with C#/BouncyCastle.